# Why does this function return a different value than if I did it inline?

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, bitmap

Having come back from a .NET high, looking to make a faster and more efficient image library I figured I'd try doing everything manually for **maximum control** <sup>*raises fist into the air*</sup>.
A learning experience, you know?

So, I'm reading some test bitmaps (.bmp extension). While reading some bitmap file headers, I noticed the size block gives me negative values.

I've managed to track down the issue somewhat, but I'm not that great at debugging. When I replace my `get_u32` function with the same chunk of code - inline - it gives me the right size. I imagine there is some implicit type conversion going on under the hood, but I can't really tell.

Here's the relevant code

```
typedef struct IMGLIB_API{
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned short reserved1;
    unsigned short reserved2;
    unsigned long offbits;
} BITMAP_FILE_HEADER;

unsigned short get_u16(char b0, char b1){
    return ((b1 << 8) | b0);
}

unsigned long get_u32(char b0, char b1, char b2, char b3){
    return (b3 << 24) | (b2 << 16) | (b1 << 8) | b0;
}

IMAGE_DATA bitmap_loader(const char* file_path){
    IMAGE_DATA r;
    ifstream ifs;
    const unsigned short valid_formats[] = {
        16973, // BM - Windows 3.1x, 95, NT, ...
        16961, // BA - OS/2 struct bitmap array
        17225, // CI - OS/2 struct color icon
        17232, // CP - OS/2 const color pointer
        18755, // IC - OS/2 struct icon
        20564  // PT - OS/2 pointer
    };
    const int BMP_FILE_HEADER_SIZE = 14;

    ifs.open(file_path, ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
    unsigned char* rhead = new unsigned char[BMP_FILE_HEADER_SIZE];
    ifs.read((char*)rhead, BMP_FILE_HEADER_SIZE);

    BITMAP_FILE_HEADER bmp_header;
    bmp_header.type = get_u16(rhead[0], rhead[1]);
    bmp_header.size = get_u32(rhead[2], rhead[3], rhead[4], rhead[5]); // - doesn't work
    //bmp_header.size = (rhead[5] << 24) | (rhead[4] << 16) | (rhead[3] << 8) | rhead[2]; // - works
    bmp_header.reserved1 = get_u16(rhead[6], rhead[7]);
    bmp_header.reserved2 = get_u16(rhead[8], rhead[9]);
    bmp_header.offbits = get_u32(rhead[10], rhead[11], rhead[12], rhead[13]); // correct, reports 54 bytes

    // TODO: check if valid bitmap type
    // TODO: read the dib header
    // TODO: read in pixel data and decompress (if needed)

    r.size = bmp_header.size;
    r.type = img_type::IM_BITMAP;

    ifs.close();
    delete rhead;
    rhead = 0;
    return r;
}
```

As an example, when loading a particular bitmap with a size of 86 454 bytes, I get -74 when using the function `get_u32`. I figured that setting the return as unsigned, and the struct member to unsigned would mean it can't be.. signed. Better rename myself to Snow, because apparently I know nothing *grumble*

Feel free to give some tips on optimizations/better ways to go about it.

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example.

Comment: You might have a problem with padding in your struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` can be signed or unsigned.  A signed char when converted to a larger type sign extends.  When you do math on a char, it converts to `int`, which is a larger type.

When doing bit manipulation, default to unsigned.

```
unsigned short get_u16(char b0, char b1){
  return ((b1 << 8) | b0);
}
```

is an example of the problem.  `b0` is sign extended, maybe.

Implementations are free to treat char as either signed or unsigned.

Comment: Oh! Oh, I see it now. That's a silly mistake. After making the arguments into `unsigned char` it works. Clearly, I didn't make everything unsigned >_< That also explains why it worked inline, because there they were already `unsigned char`

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't see the need. The OP should be able to add the word `unsigned` next to the word `char` without me doing it for'm.  Are you saying my answer would be better if I copy/pasted the OP's code then ran a regex on it?

Comment: @kfsone I disagree, doing `s/char/unsigned char/` simply makes the answer worse.  I even stated so in my comment above, prior to your edit.  Feel free to add another answer if you choose!